# How do I insert a text column in siunitx tabular

Tags: tables, siunitx

I would like to insert a text column in a table for which other columns are formatted by siunitx

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r
            S[table-format = 2.1]
            S[table-format = 2]}
\toprule
overlay & SS & df\\
\midrule
Data & 72.9 & 29\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'd'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`siunitx` will try to 'guess' which entries are non-numerical, but it works much more cleanly if you mark them up using braces or `\multicolumn`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r
            S[table-format = 2.1]
            S[table-format = 2]}
\toprule
overlay & SS & {df}\\
\midrule
Data & 72.9 & 29\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ r
            S[table-format = 2.1]
            S[table-format = 2]}
\toprule
overlay & SS & \multicolumn{1}{c}{df}\\
\midrule
Data & 72.9 & 29\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```